# Ability to query SQL Server with Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper

I use Oracle SQL Developer to query Oracle databases. I now need to connect to a SQL Server database in order to query the data. I was told I needed a JAR file. I'm not very technical, if anyone can help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68771/connecting-to-sql-server-using-oracle-sql-developer

Comment: Similar to how SQL Server uses Linked Server connections to access other databases Oracle has Heterogeneous Services. Have a read through [Database Heterogeneous Connectivity User's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HETER/toc.htm).

Comment: Also refer to the post on connecting to SQL Server from ORACLE Sql Developere: http://www.snapdba.com/2013/10/using-sql-developer-to-connect-to-sql-server-databases/#.Xa_T7egzZPY